# Some keys seem dead - Works in Safe Mode

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, hotkeys, dead-keys

Recently, some key(-combinations) have stopped working on my WinXP Pro SP3 computer. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> seem dead on the numpad, but all other keys and combinations work as they should.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> does work with <kbd>Shift</kbd> added and with <kbd>NumLock</kbd> on + <kbd>Shift</kbd>, but not with <kbd>NumLock</kbd> alone.

Numpad <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd> also work with <kbd>Shift</kbd> added, and with <kbd>NumLock</kbd> on, but not with <kbd>NumLock</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

This behavior occurs across all programs, and has only appeared recently. Never saw anything like it in this machine’s first 2 years.

I have uninstalled various programs and halted processes, to no avail. It seems something has hijacked these keys, but I can’t find out what.

NB: In Safe Mode, all keys work as they should - no dead keys, no need to add <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>NumLock</kbd>.

I hope somebody here has an idea what is going on – and how to stop it.

Comment: Try using `MSConfig` to narrow down which service or startup program is doing it.  Uncheck all non-MS stuff -- See if it works. Turn on Service A, reboot, does it work? Yes, turn on service B, reboot, does it still work? Turn on Service C, reboot. etc.

Comment: @nitro2k01 Thx, fixed it. :)

Comment: Is this a laptop keyboard or external keyboard? If laptop have you tried connecting a an external USB keyboard?

Comment: With MSconfig, I disabled all non-MS startup programs and services, but on reboot the problem persisted. :(

Comment: BTW, this is a desktop PC with external keyboard. I tried another keyboard - same problem.  I have a hunch that a recent upgrade of Adobe Flash Player plugin (to 11.9.900.170) has something to do with it, but I wouldn't know how, and it's only a hunch.

Comment: In the end, I found the curprit: Skype. Disabling it on StartUp prevents these key-hijacks. I wonder if other Skype-users have problems with Ctrl-E and/or NumPad PgUp&PgDn outside Skype.